# Move errors to the bottom in checkout Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, onestepcheckout

I need to move the error messages at magento 2 checkout to the bottom of the page. I noticed that payment errors are within the "payment-method-content" div, but I didn't find a way to move elsewhere. How can I do this?

Comment: well, it will move success message too. is it OK ?

Comment: Yes, it will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create `checkout_index_index.xml` at:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/layout

with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="checkout" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.messages" destination="before.body.end" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope above will help!

Comment: If `page.messages` not work, you can use `messages` instead.

Comment: I've tried this two ways, but it don't works :/

Comment: When I try to do this, i see a console error. "Options cannot be loaded"

Comment: Sorry, the error is  "Options is undefined"